# Azure DevOps Unable to find file "requirements.txt"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mlops

everyone!

First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to read this question. Without further delay, let me explain my situation.

I'm using Azure DevOps, specifically the Pipelines feature. I have a machine learning model, and I want to set up continuous integration and continuous deployment (CI/CD). My entire project is stored in the Azure Repos control code system.

I want to make sure I'm following best practices. I've already created and run my unit tests, and now I want to install the Python packages listed in my **requirements.txt** file.

*Here are my questions and the issues I'm facing:*

**Question:**

When I start the pipeline, and the agent begins its work, is it necessary to run requirements.txt? I mean, why is it needed? I'm not using that agent as a server or deployment source, so couldn't I do this with a Docker image or another method?

***Error:***
When I run the job, I encounter an error that says it can't find the requirements.txt file.

To give you an idea of my project structure, it looks like this:

```
myreponame/
    - folder1/
        - myfile.py
    - requirements/
        - requirements.txt
```

and my pipeline script looks like this:

```
# Check Branches
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

# Set VM Before Deploying
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

# Starting Step
steps:
- script: |
    # Install Dependencies
    echo Checking and Installing Dependencies
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install python3  # Install Python 3 (or python for Python 2)
- script: |
    echo Running Unit Tests
    python -m unittest discover -s test -p "*_test.py"
  displayName: 'Running Tests'
- script: |
    # Create a virtual environment
    # python -m venv myenv
    # source myenv/bin/activate
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'
```

The error I'm encountering is:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements/requirements.txt'
```

I also tried:

```
pip install -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/requirements/requirements.txt
```

But that gave me:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/requirements/requirements.txt'
```

I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong because I'm new to DevOps, especially in the context of MLops.

Can someone please help me understand what's going wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Add `ls -r` before `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in your last task. Trigger a pipeline and check if you can see the requirements in the log.  If you can't, the reason of the issue is that the requirements.txt isn't in your current working directory.  Do you have any other branches besides `main` in your repo? If you have, check which branch triggered the build, you can see it from the Summary page. It's better that you could share some screenshots of the structure of your repo and the build summary page of your failed build.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you've not checked out your repository.

To the pipeline, before you start your steps add the repository as a resource:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
```

Then, in your steps make sure your first step is to use your repos:

```yaml
  steps:
  - checkout: self
```

If you still face issues you should add some logging showing your working path and list the directories. That will help you to figure out your exact path you need.

Comment: Truly appreciate your feedback, I added the lines that you mentioned (however not sure it was in the right section), I would appreciate if you could provide few more feedbacks on my YAML 
` # Set VM Before Deploying
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
resources: 
 repositories:
   - repository: self
# Starting Step
steps:
- checkout: self `

Comment: See my other comment, did you try the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) path. I suspect you're in the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

The reason why it was failing : the pipeline was checking the branch "master" instead of Main but now new problems arose, anyway Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: did you try the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) path. I suspect you're in the wrong directory. Also, it would be better to delete this answer and update your original post.